# identifying expansion series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, special-functions

Consider
$$
f(x;a)=\sum_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^k[(1+a)^{i+2}-(i+2)a-1],
$$
where $a>0$. Can the series in the right-hand side be reduced to (or is it) to a more compact form (e.g., a special function of some sort)?